# Manual Cron job occasionally outputting WP die message

Tags: cron

I have some manual cron jobs running on my server hourly - they seem to generally fire fine, but occasionally they output the WP die message page html (see below) to the cron output logs which i have set up. Any ideas what could be the cause of this?

```
...  .button:active {
                        background: #eee;
                        border-color: #999;
                        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
                        box-shadow: inset 0 2px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
                }

                        </style>
</head>
<body id="error-page">
        <div class="wp-die-message"><p>There has been a critical error on your website.</p><p><a href="https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Learn more about debugging in WordPress.</a></p></div></body>
</html>
```

I also have debugging turned on but don't see anything in `debug.log`

Comment: You'd probably need to show the code that's actually being run on cron.

Comment: **A quick tip for getting great answers**: Many experts are busy people. Help them get to all the facts as soon as possible (without asking follow up questions) and you will get many more answers. Check [our guide to asking good questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need to.